# Set the type for generic method C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, generics, type-conversion

I just started coding in Java again and I'm converting some code from C# into Java for a small project, to get started in Java again. 
My problem is with how to specify what type of instance I want back from a generic method. 
In C# I'd do something like this:

```
const int B = 1;
const int C = 2;
int classType = a given value
ClassB : ClassA
ClassC : ClassA

private ClassA CreateClone(ClassA classToBeCloned){
    switch(classType){
        case B:
            return classToBeCloned.CreateClone<ClassB>(); 
        case C:
            return classToBeCloned.CreateClone<ClassC>();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And as such as above I can retrieve different implementations of ClassA depending on the variable classType. 
However, in Java I cannot do (or atleast the Netbeans 8.0 IDE signals error when doing it) the same. Basically I cannot tell the method what type I want back (call below is what I want in java):

```
classToBeCloned.CreateClone<Class*>();
Where * = B or C
```

So how do I specify what type the method should send back? (More like,what T should be inside the method)

Might be diffuse, not an expert in expressing myself properly, haha. 
All help appreciated!

Comment: You're missing the point, might be my mistake. B and C are integer constants, nothing to do with my issue. The switch works properly, I can't see how I can do classToBeCloned.CreateClone<WantedClass>() in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to locate the generic information at a different spot for Java:

```
return classToBeCloned.<ClassB>CreateClone();
```